# Can jmx (Java 11) be disabled from allowing local access while still allowing remote access?

Tags: java-11, jmx, jconsole

After migrating from Java 8 to Java 11, our internal code that allowed jmx / jconsole no longer worked.  Following the Java 11 guidelines using the standard config / password files, I got things working, however, I do not want to allow local access.

More specifically, I want to force authentication.

Here is the code that worked fine with Java 8.  It does not fail with Java 11, but jconsole cannot connect.

```
    InetAddress bindIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    String jmxUrl = JmxUtils.createJmxServerUrl(bindIpAddress, port);

    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", bindIpAddress.getHostAddress());

    logger.info("Starting JMX connectorServer.");
    try {
        final SSLContext sslContext = initializeSslContext();
        final HashMap<String, Object> env = new HashMap<>();
        final RMIServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory = new GridServerSocketFactory();
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port, null, serverSocketFactory);
        env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(sslContext, null, null, false));
        env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory());
        env.put("jmx.remote.authenticator", JmxUtils.createUserAuthenticator(user, password));
        connectorServer = new RMIConnectorServer(
                new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl),
                env,
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        connectorServer.start();
        running = true;
    }
    catch (IOException|GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("Exception starting JMX connectorServer", e);
    }
```

To get it to work, I just added this to where we start the JVM, with a *different* port than the code above uses:

- `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`
- `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25943`
- `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false`

That allows me to connect (though lacking the internal SSL config we had before) either locally without any authentication, or remotely with authentication.

I have not been able to find a way to disable local access, and local access gives full privileges to jconsole.  If I could disable local access, allowing only remote access, that would be help immensely....but how?  It is easily configurable for local-only, but I sure can't find anything documented for remote-only.

***OR maybe better***, is there something I need to add to the original code (that worked with Java 8) to get that to work with Java 11? This would be more ideal.

**UPDATE (2023-08-08):** The Java-11 JDK doesn't include a jconsole.jar, which is why I went down this path and ran into the above "local access" issues with jconsole.exe.  I just discovered, however, that if I simply use the jconsole.jar that's in the Java-8 jdk, everything works fine under Java-11 with our original code. Zero changes. I think that is the route I'm going to take, **but**, *does anyone know why jconsole.jar stopped being included in the JDK in 11, when it was present in 8?*  (FWIW, we're using Azul.)